# Data classification in Matlab using KNN

Tags: matlab, knn

I have an dataset for employees in an organization that I need to classify into 3 groups:

- **Normal Data**: Employees with salaries less than 50000$ and job title contains "Assistant"
- **Important Data**: Employees with salaries between "50000" and "100000" and job title contains "Director".
- **Critical data**: Employees with salaries more than 100000$ and job title contains "Deputy".

I wrote the below code in Matlab and used `fitcknn` but I received the following error:

```
Error using classreg.learning.FullClassificationRegressionModel.prepareDataCR (line 192)
X must be a numeric matrix.

Error in classreg.learning.classif.FullClassificationModel.prepareData (line 487)
                classreg.learning.FullClassificationRegressionModel.prepareDataCR(...

Error in ClassificationKNN.prepareData (line 878)
                prepareData@classreg.learning.classif.FullClassificationModel(X,Y,varargin{:},'OrdinalIsCategorical',true);

Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate/fit (line 213)
                    this.PrepareData(X,Y,this.BaseFitObjectArgs{:});

Error in ClassificationKNN.fit (line 863)
            this = fit(temp,X,Y);

Error in fitcknn (line 261)
    this = ClassificationKNN.fit(X,Y,RemainingArgs{:});

Error in WhiteHouse (line 11)
MDL = fitcknn (B,G,'NumNeighbors',5,'standardize',1);
```

Please I need help to see what is missing in my code.

```
    %Training Data
    B= [ "" "Employee" 50000 "Per Annum" "Assistant" ; "" "Employee" 100000 "Per Annum" "Director" ; "" "" 150000 "Per Annum" "Deputy" ] ;

    % Labels
    G = [ "Normal" ; "Important"  ; "Critical" ] ;
    %SampleData
    A = ["Brundage" "Employee" 103000 "Per Annum" "SPECIAL" ; "Buffa Nicole" "Employee" 80000  "Per Annum" "DEPUTY DIRECTOR OF CABINET AFFAIRS" ] ;

    MDL = fitcknn (B,G,'NumNeighbors',5,'standardize',1);
    class = predict (MDL,A)
    disp ('Result:') ;
    disp (class) ;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. While you're editing, clarify what you mean when you write "did not work". Please read [ask].

Comment: I have updated my question now with the code.

Answer (score 0):

As wrotten in the error message, the argument is invalid.
Your `B` variable is a cell containing numeric and text data.
It should be numeric only and not a cell array.

Please refer to the example in the documentation.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcknn.html#bt6d3vt-2